# How to pass a variable from a template to a view in Django

Tags: django

I am not able to GET a variable from a template into another view.

I have a table with some records. Each row has a button which I would like to click and retrieve more details about the record in another page. I have been looking online but I cannot figure out how I should implement this. Everything I have tried either crashed or gave back None.

list.html

```
{% for trainee in trainees_list %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ trainee.last_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ trainee.first_name }}</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'traineedetails'%}" value="{{ trainee.pk }}" >View</a></td>
          </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

view.py

```
def traineedetails(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        trainee_details = request.POST.get('trainee.pk')
        print(trainee_details)
        return render(request, 'trainee_details.html')

def listoftrainees(request):
    trainees_list = UserTraining.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('list.html', {'trainees_list': trainees_list})
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('traineedetails', views.traineedetails, name='traineedetails'),
    path('listoftrainees', views.listoftrainees, name='listoftrainees'),
]
```

form.py

```
class UserTrainingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    scope_requirements = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=microscopes.MICROSCOPES)

    class Meta:
        model = UserTraining

        fields = (
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        )
```

model.py

```
class UserTraining(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField('first name', max_length = 100)
    last_name = models.CharField('last name', max_length = 100)
```

I would like to be able to click on the button in the row of the table and retrive more information about the record.

Comment: Your URLs are wrong. In a good REST-ful application, your URLs should be: 1. For the list of trainees: `/trainees/` and 2. for a specific trainee: `/trainees/<pk>`. So change your url patterns, especially the trainee details one to something like `path('trainees/<int:pk>, ...)` then in your template you can refer to it with `{% url 'traineedetails' pk=trainee.pk %}`. The `pk` is then passed to your view as argument so `def traineedetails(request, pk): ....` no need to fetch it from the `request`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I wonder how you would fetch it from the request.

Answer (score 4):

You pass the value directly in the url like : `traineedetails/<pk>`

In the template:

```
{% for trainee in trainees_list %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ trainee.last_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ trainee.first_name }}</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'traineedetails' trainee.pk%}">View</a></td>
          </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Edit your urls.py:

```
path('traineedetails/<pk>', views.traineedetails, name='traineedetails'),
```

Then you can retrieve it in your view like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
def traineedetails(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        #try to get your objet or throw a 404 error
        trainee = get_object_or_404(UserTraining, pk=pk)
        #pass it back to the template
        return render(request, 'trainee_details.html',{'trainee':trainee})
```